# Confused by proof: limsup is a limit point of the sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I'm confused by "Since $sup_{j > k}x_j$ is finite ...

because how do you know there exists an $x_l$ such that $|x_l - sup_{j > k}x_j| \leq 1/2n$? What if the sequence is just $1,0,0,0,0,0,\cdots$, and so the  difference between the $sup$ and any other point is just 1? Is it implying that $x_l$ be the sup? That would work because $|x_l - sup_{j > k}x_j| = 0$, but I think that's a wrong reading. It's almost treating $sup_{j > k}x_j$ as a limit even though it's not.

[image]

Comment: $\sup_{j>k} x_j$ means you ignore $x_1, x_2, \ldots x_{k-1}, x_k$. If the sequence you have is $1,0,0,0,0,\ldots$ take $k=1$ then $\sup_{j > k} x_j = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us dissect the notation: $\sup_{j>k}x_j$

If we have a sequence $x_1,x_2,\ldots $ then at some point we hit $x_k$, and the above notation says we ignore all values prior to and including $x_k$. Hence we have a subsequence

$$x_{k+1},x_{k+2},\ldots$$
and this is what we take the sup over.

Next, the assumption is $$\lim_{k\to \infty} \sup_{j>k} x_j = y$$ is finite.

Hence, we have a bounded sequence. Moreover, by assumption $y = \lim_{k\to \infty} \sup_{j>k} x_j$ is finite so that is how they say ***since $\bf \sup_{j>k} x_j$ is finite***.

Namely $y$ is the limit of the sequence:

$$\Large \sup_{j>k_1} x_j, \sup_{j>k_2} x_j,\sup_{j>k_3} x_j,\ldots,\sup_{j>k_l} x_j, \ldots$$

EDIT:
The proof isn't implying $x_l$ is the supremum, its stating we can find a member of the sequence further down. Namely, we are getting the sufficient condition : Let $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence and if every subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{n \ge 1, k \ge 1}$ has a further subsequence $(x_{n_{k_l}})_{n \ge 1, k \ge 1, l \ge 1}$ such that it converges to $x$, then the original sequence converges to $x$.

Comment: I get the notation and what $y$ means, I just don't understand the proof in the screenshot.

Comment: I have added to my answer.